# VBA Copy the first matched value in a row to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i just want to know the correct code for copying a first matched row into another worksheet.
for example, i have duplicated values in column a, but i need to copy only the first row matched my criteria.
Column a
Row 1 AAA
Row 2 AAA
Row 3 AAA
instead of copying all matched values, i just need to copy only the first matched value to another worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

A Vlookup would bring back the first instance it found. If you want to do it using VBA then a Do Until should work.

Comment: Hi Stuart, does Do Until applicable for multiple criteria? When it matches my criteria then  it will copy the first row it matches. Then proceed with the next criteria.

Comment: Not on it's own you'd need to put it within something that went through your search criteria.  e.g.Sub Macro1()
'
Dim lCount, lLoop As Long
Dim lLookUpValue, lArrayValue As String

For lCount = 1 To 2
    lLookUpValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lCount).Value
    lLoop = 1
    Do Until lArrayValue = lLookUpValue
        lArrayValue = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lLoop).Value
        lLoop = lLoop + 1
    Loop
Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(lLoop - 1).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(lCount)

Next
End Sub